# Can I use int for the amount of strings

Tags: java, string, int

Hi just wondering if I can use int for the amount of strings I want so for instance

private-string int 6 ——

Gives me 6 strings or is there another way

Comment: this is array,in java String[] arr = new String[6];

Comment: thank you very much and also given that answer is there anyway that it can not be removed?  What would I put

Comment: It would be Java

Answer (score 0):

i dont know what language do you use but in java:

String[] arr = new String[6];

like that you have 6 String in arr. You can assign like that

arr[2] = "str";

now third element is assigned. When you want to read;

String anotherStr = arr[2];

Comment: Right so just by doing that you then then use arr8 and then that’s 8str